# Decoding Django POST request body

Tags: python, jquery, json, django, post

I'm building an mapping app using cordova and making a post request sending  the following JSON (feature)

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        -6.6865857,
        53.2906136
    ]
},
"properties": {
    "amenity": "pub",
    "name": "The Parade Ring"
}
```

}

This is the JQuery code sending the request

```
function savePub(feature){

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    headers: {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken},
    url: HOST + URLS["savePub"],
    data: {
        pub_feature: JSON.stringify(feature)
    },
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).done(function (data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data + " " + status);
    pubDialogAlert("Pub saved",feature);
}).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    showOkAlert(error);
    console.log(status + " " + error);
    console.log(xhr);
}).always(function () {
    $.mobile.navigate("#map-page");
});
```

}

When the request is received in the Django backend I am not sure why when I print the request body it looks like this,

```
b'pub_feature=%22%7B%5C%22type%5C%22%3A%5C%22Feature%5C%22%2C%5C%22geometry%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22type%5C%22%3A%5C%22Point%5C%22%2C%5C%22coordinates%5C%22%3A%5B-6.6865857%2C53.2906136%5D%7D%2C%5C%22properties%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22amenity%5C%22%3A%5C%22pub%5C%22%2C%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%5C%22The+Parade+Ring%5C%22%7D%7D%22'
```

and when I try to decode it and then use json.loads() it throws this error

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def save_pub(request):
if request.method == "POST":

    data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    received_json_data = json.loads(data)

    return Response(str(received_json_data) + " written to db", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


JSONDecodeError at /savepub/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I am assuming because once it decodes the binary string it can't be converted to valid JSON because of those characters %22 etc, but I don't know what the solution is.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to remove `pub_feature=` and then  `url = urllib.unquote(request.body.decode('utf-8'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up two things here, form-encoded and JSON format. What you have is a form-encoded post with one key, `pub_feature`, whose value is a JSON object.

Instead you should post the JSON directly:

```
data: JSON.stringify(feature),
```

and then you should be able to load it as you do already - although note that really you should let DRF deal with that for you

Comment: Thank you. Changing the POST to data: JSON.stringify(feature) and using the Django Rest Framework worked..